# Cannot use jQuery in Blade

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel with it's Blade template engine and I'm running into a bit of an issue using jQuery.

I have a master template called master.blade.php. In this file, I have my various CSS and JS files that will be used site wide. In order to organize things better, I have individual JS files included only on the blade pages that use them. These templates use the @extends feature and "inherit" the master.blade.php template.

When I do this, I receive the JS error:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

When I put the JS file on the master.blade.php template, it works. I've double checked my load order to make sure that jQuery is loaded first, so I'm a bit confused as to the reason.

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is the classic "jQuery not found" error. Something is causing jQuery to be unavailable when you are attempting to use it, but it is hard to provide specifics without seeing your code.

Comment: Did you check when you are accessing `$`? Seems you are accessing `$` before including the script. Can you post your source code?

Comment: Also, try changing `$` to `jQuery`.

Comment: Yes, I tried all of those. I think it has to do with the Blade template engine.

Comment: I'm assuming your page does not have jquery loaded. or it is loaded as no conflicts in its own namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    /* now you can use $ */
});
```

Comment: THIS WORKED!! Don't know how, but it did. Thanks.